# C program to read the contents of the file and pass it to an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I want to read the contents of a text file and copy it to 3 arrays. The first 14 lines to 'a' array, next 14 to 'b' array and remaining to c. When I press one to enter the choice, it must display the first 14 lines of the .txt file. When I compile this code which I have given, it gives only the first character to the whole array. Please help and thanks in advance.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
int x,i;
char *a[100],*b[100],*c[100];
FILE *stream,*out;
char ch;
clrscr();
stream=fopen("test.txt","r");
while((ch=fgetc(stream))!=EOF)
{
for(i=0;i<14;i++)
a[i]==ch;
//ch=fgetc(stream);
//printf("%c",ch);
}
fclose(stream);
printf("Enter your choice");
scanf("%d",&x);
switch(x)
{
case 1:
    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
    printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    break;
case 2:
    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
    printf("%s\n",b[i]);
    break;
case 3:
    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
    printf("%s\n",c[i]);
    break;
case 4:
    exit(0);
default:
    printf("Invalid choice");
    break;
}
getch();
}
```

Current Output:
Enter your choice1
n
n
n
n
n
n
n
n
n
n
n
n

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger on the system and toolchain of your choice. This is a simple problem that a debugger can help to solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef char *CP14[14];

int main(){
    int x,i;
    char *a[14], *b[14], *c[14];
    CP14 *abcp, *p[] = {&a, &b, &c, NULL};
    char buffer[14*3*128]={0};//128 : max of one line
    FILE *stream;
    int ch, nlcount=0;//ch is int for fgetc
    int gp = 0;

    stream=fopen("test.txt","r");

    abcp = p[gp];
    (*abcp)[0]=&buffer[0];
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(buffer)-1 && (ch=fgetc(stream))!=EOF;++i){
        if('\n'== (buffer[i] = ch)){
            buffer[i]= '\0';
            if(++nlcount == 14){
                nlcount = 0;
                if(NULL == (abcp = p[++gp]))
                    break;
            }
            (*abcp)[nlcount]=&buffer[i+1];
        }
    }
    fclose(stream);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the while loop if you know that the file is going to have 14*3 characters.

Simply read them in three consecutive for loops. Something like:

```
for(i=0;i<14;++i)
    a[i]=fgetc(stream));
for(i=0;i<14;++i)
    b[i]=fgetc(stream));
for(i=0;i<14;++i)
    c[i]=fgetc(stream));
```

Also, `==` is a comparison and not assignment operator.